# Get smallest type to include data range

Tags: c++, templates, boost, std, c++03

Is there already a mechanism in `std` or `boost` to retrieve the smallest type, which can hold both any value of `Type1` and `Type2` with `Type1` and `Type2` being numeric types (int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, unsigned variants).